# does this equation has an answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is the equation:$$x=\log(a+bx),$$ where $a$ and $b$ satisfies the conditions that let the equation makes sense. Does it have an answer that can be expressed explicitly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to specify what type of values $a,b$ and $x$ are in. For example, can $a,b$ or $x$ be complex-valued? The tag (diophantine-equations) suggest that $a,b$ and $x$ are integers but you may want to state it clearly in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does it have an answer that can be expressed explicitly?*

It can be expressed in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), as follows: $$x=\log_n(ax+b)\iff n^x=ax+b\iff e^{x\ln n}=\underbrace{ax+b}_y\iff\exp\bigg[\frac{y-b}a\cdot\ln n\bigg]=y$$

$$\iff\exp\bigg[y\cdot\frac{\ln n}a\bigg]\cdot\exp\bigg[-\frac ba\cdot\ln n\bigg]=y\iff n^{^{-\tfrac ba}}=y\cdot\exp\bigg[\underbrace{-y\cdot\frac{\ln n}a}_t\bigg]\iff$$

$$\iff-\,n^{^{-\tfrac ba}}\cdot\frac{\ln n}a=t\cdot e^t\iff t=W\bigg(-\,n^{^{-\tfrac ba}}\cdot\frac{\ln n}a\bigg)\iff y=-\frac a{\ln n}\cdot t\iff$$

$$x=\frac{y-b}a=-\frac ba-\frac t{\ln n}=-\frac ba-\frac{W\bigg(-\,n^{^{-\tfrac ba}}\cdot\dfrac{\ln n}a\bigg)}{\ln n}$$